# How to deploy a MDM check-in sever？

Tags: mdm, checkin

My Configuration Profile with MDM Payload not getting installed using IPCU，I have a P12 file， Did the P12 file have any relationship with the check-in server? And how to deploy a MDM check-in server to solve the problem?

Comment: Is title misspelled or it is some term related to whatever you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the identity.p12 should related to your server.Your server link must start with "https"

If you are using self-signed ssl then,While generating self-signed ssl certificate in server side,generate identity.p12 certificate and this certificate you need to use in identity section of IPCU and use the same password also.

These few lines you can use to generate the idendtity.p12

```
//Creating the device Identity key and certificate request

openssl genrsa 2048 > identity.key
openssl req -new -key identity.key -out identity.csr


//Signing the identity key with the CA. 
//Give it a passphrase. You'll need to include that in the IPCU profile.

openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in identity.csr -CA cacert.crt -CAkey cakey.key -CAcreateserial -out identity.crt

openssl pkcs12 -export -out identity.p12 -inkey identity.key -in identity.crt -certfile cacert.crt
```

To deploy the server go through [MDM_Protocol](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Schuetz/BH_US_11_Schuetz_InsideAppleMDM_WP.pdf) pdf in which sample server details is there.