# Certificates confusion in MDM

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I was able to develop a mdm solution.

I started facing problem when I moved my agent from Developer account's provisioning profile to Enterprise account's in-house distribution profile.

Now I am totally confused which certificate is used where?

Please guide me his is the certificate used in the below places:

1. Certificate in credentials section of enrollment profile (is it having BI as com.apple.mgmt.*_*  ? or can be any like com.abc.mdm ? or it's the one received by customer)
2. Certificate .pem file used to wake up device?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use your iOS Enterprise developer account use the Agent account's credentials.

- Follow this page http://www.softhinker.com/in-the-news/iosmdmvendorcsrsigning and then verify few things as remove the passphrase from customerPrivateKey.pem using this command

  openssl rsa -in customerPrivateKey.pem -out PlainKey.pem
- Verify the .pem certificate downloaded from https://identity.apple.com/pushcert/

  You can install this .pem in you Mac's Keychain and then see the Get Info and the certificate should have  com.apple.mgmt.External.b503419d-1e2a-a60f-7451-5b8832b5a9cb, which you can use as push topic while generating enroll mobileconfig .
- Then merge your APNS certificate (for example CustomerCompanyName.pem) downloaded from the portal https://identity.apple.com/pushcert/ using this command

  cat CustomerCompanyName.pem PlainKey.pem > PlainCert.pem

Now the PlainCert.pem you can use as APNS/MDM certificate.

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491789/how-to-deploy-a-mdm-check-in-sever/10670590#10670590) for Identity.p12 and respective password, which you have to use in Credential section.

Comment: I ported the softhinker java code to python. It's available here: https://github.com/grinich/mdmvendorsign

Answer (score 2):

1) it HAS to be com.apple.mgmt._ however this does not come from the provisioning portal - all you can set up here is your vendor certificate. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10348759/1132403)

2) the certificate is used to make the connection to the APNS service, but you should get this from the the [Apple Push Certificates Portal](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=apns%20cert%20portal&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CF8QFjAD&url=https://identity.apple.com/pushcert/&ei=uITDT92vEMyt8QPn4PjRCg&usg=AFQjCNFXQ1eEUH_KhS0OnoDUzPbDv1W6eg&sig2=pmBLoNcTlWjKeAAGC7PA8w)

Comment: Thanks Abstractec,

I again have some doubts based on your above comment: 

1. Do we need to use Push SSL Certificates with App ID as com.apple.mgmt._  OR We need to use the MDM Vendors certificates in the Credentials section 

2. From Apple Push Certificate, we used which of the below for device wake up:
    1. Certificates for Third-Party Servers
    2. Certificates for OS X Server


In Point 1, if we want to use production Push SSL Certificates, then I am not able to understand how its distinguished for Development and Production mode.

Please help

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you mean. You need to create a vendor solution. See link in (1). I have no idea what you mean by 'wake up device', but all MDM requests use the certificate received from the Apple Push Certificates Portal.

Comment: I generated push certificate for MDM. Its got a valid subject/topic. When viewed in keychain store it says "This certificate was signed by an unknown authority". There's also no private key associated with it. Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: @Abstractec - Please help me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192211/setting-wallpaper-using-mdm