# Setting wallpaper using mdm

Tags: ios, xml, mdm

I want to set device's lock and home wallpaper using mdm command.

I looking into apple configuration but didn't find any xml that can be used to set the wallpapers.

Please help for getting me the XML.

Answer (score 1):

Apple didn't release new configuration profile reference guide for iOS 7 yet.

If you really want to try it, go and disassemble managedconfiguration private framework. It contains info on all payloads.

Answer (score 0):

You can set lockscreen with Apple Configurator however the background option is not present in current Apple Configurator(Please note ac is not updated since IOS 7.
Regarding settings lockscreen and background in "mdm" it depends on what mdm "brand" you'r using.